# Unexplainable Column swap on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridviewcolumn

I have the following datatable:

```
 DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fupcpe10", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fupcpe1", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Flowcpe10", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Flowcpe1", typeof(double))); ;
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gcpe10", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gcpe1", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hcpe10", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hcpe1", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Icpe10", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Icpe1", typeof(double))); 
                dt4.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Variavel", typeof(double))); 
                foreach (DataRow row in rows4)
                {
                    dt4.ImportRow(row);
                }
```

In the same context `rows4` is a 2D array that contains 2 rows of other table.

However, this happens:

[image]

The columns are misteriously swaped, i looked around and the only thing that should do this is a direct index swap, which i have none on my code. Hints?

What i expected was this column order

[image]

The rows4 is formed after this

```
DataRow[] rows = DataAccess.Instance.tabela1vert0caso1W.Select("Variavel = " + min.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " OR " + "Variavel = " + max.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

where `tabela1vert0caso1W` is the table with the correct order!

tl;dr: I create a table `tabela1vert0caso1W`which works fine, i take 2 rows of it and place them in `rows4` Then i create datatable `dt4` with the same columns in the same order, and place the 2 rows there. Somewhere in this process the swap happens, just where? how? I have dozens of other tables and nothing like this ever happened

Comment: It is not really clear what you expect(and why) and what happened instead? Where is the code you generate `rows4` ?

Comment: Turn off `AutoGenerateColumns` (you might have to rebind after change)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Aren't the columns indexed in the same order you add them to the table? I will edit my question anyways

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, the problem is that I had similar, but not exactly equal tables above with the columns in different order., this has surely something to do with AutoGenerateColumns as DonBoitnott commented.

Anyways to reset it just null the dataGridView before applying the new table

```
dataGridView6.DataSource = null;
dataGridView6.DataSource = dt4;
```

This will somehow "reset" the columns order. I hope this helps someone else.